# Search in MySQL with Spaces

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am creating an app similar to *Instagram*. I have a `photos` table with a `likers` columns, showing which `user_id`s have liked a photo. For example, if `user_id` 1 and 5 like `photo_id` 51, then `photo_id` 51's `likers` column will show `1 5`. As seen, the `user_id`s are separated by spaces. Now, like Instagram, I want to be able to show which username's are liking a specific photo. For this, I need to be able to get all the `user_id`s from the `likers` column separately. Can anyone help me with how to do this, or suggest an alternative way?

Comment: consider a junction/intersect table and save them as a separate row ?

Comment: You need to take a step back and learn about Database Normal Forms.  This goes against the fourth normal form of relational databases.  You don't store multiple values in a field.  Instead you would have multiple records in a table called, 'photo_likers' that would have a foreign key of the photo_id of the 'photos' table.  That photo_likers table would then be relational, and would have a one to many relationship with the 'photos' table.

Comment: I read both of your comments and will study Normal Forms. I'm just trying to self-learn mysql rn so I have some gaps, but I had done this type of thing for another comments feature. Where comments table has comments and then photo_Id. Not sure why I didn't consider using it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're approaching this the wrong way. You almost certainly don't want to store multiple pieces of data in one field. You want to have something like this:

```
Table: User
- id
- blah blah

Table: Photo
- id
- blah blah

Table: Like
- user_id
- photo_id
```

This will allow you write very flexible queries, including what you described:

```
SELECT u.id
FROM User AS u
JOIN Like AS li ON li.user_id = u.id
WHERE li.photo_id = $current_photo_id
```

This is a topic known as [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). Please read more about it if you want your application to succeed.

Comment: Just to add, the  `like` table is also known as a pivot table, which allows a many to many relationship between the `user` and `photo` tables. A user can have many photos, a photo can be liked by many users.

Comment: Dr E.F. Codd would be proud

Comment: Makes sense. thank you! I'll mark it as the correct answer as soon as it allows me to.

Comment: just tell me what is `blah` ? :-)

Comment: I was hoping you'd go into "Normal Forms" and would have directed the OP to study them. However, your solution is correct.  But my opinion is that you need to give the root of your solution as well to encourage proper understanding of WHY this is the best approach.