# Need help in creating a student database

Tags: optimization, database-design

I'm creating a project/web portal for the college database where I have to store students attendance percentage and their grades in various subjects. Currently, I have designed the database as follows. I need to know whether it is a good method of storing data.

Master Table:

```
Id | roll_number | Department | Year_of_study
```

Table for adding attendance percentage for each student:

```
Id | roll_number(foreign key) | Attendance_for_period1 | Attendance_for_period2
```

Table for adding subjects:

```
Id | Subject_name

1   | computer Programming

2   | Data structures

3   | professional ethics

.   
. 
.
```

Table for adding grades for each student in various subjects:

```
Id | roll_number(foreign key) | Marks_in_period1 | Marks_in_period2 
1  | 412811104092             | A,B,A,B,C,D      | B,C,A,A,D,F
```

In Marks_in_period1 column, comma separates grades for each subject (i.e) I have inserted marks for 6 subjects. Is the database correct or need any optimisation?

Comment: Never store anything in a comma separated list. That's just asking for trouble. Use 3rd normal form.

Comment: Your table design is terribly denormalized. Your grades table is storing multiple values in a single intersection. It also has repeating groups (period1, period2) This violates 1NF. Your attendance table has repeating groups (period1, period2). This also violates 1NF. Your master table appears to be problematic also because you don't have a department table. I am not sure what this question has to do with php and you need to pick a DBMS. sql server <> mysql.

Comment: "I need to know whether it is a good method of storing data." No its not

Comment: @SeanLange Repeating groups ? I cant get u. Can u explain it in clear.And I have department table but I didn't display it here.

Comment: Repeating groups is things like Period1, Period2. When you structure your table like this you have to change the table and all the queries to add a Period3. This is bad. You should instead spin the periods off to another table so it doesn't matter how many periods there are.

Answer (score 1):

You should (almost) never store multiple pieces of data in a single field. Not only does it make it very hard to search inside, you also have to parse the data every time you read/serialize every time you write.

[Take a look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31420552/5113242).

Comment: I have read that answer. But in my case I have students and their grades for various subjects. So with your solution I can say that I can create a table with student roll no , grade and subject (3 columns). Is that right? But if i do like this i will have same roll no for different subjects with different grades. Is that ok ?

Comment: That sounds about right. You can play with your schema on http://sqlfiddle.com/ . Once you have something, paste it here and I'll take a look.

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate your help :)

Comment: Can you explain the "period_1" and "period_2" fields? Also do you expect attendance to be entered as a single value or yes/no for each class?

Comment: period represents a particular checkpoint  in a semester. Actually, for a semester there will be two periods with a exam in each period. Attendance represents percentage of attendance student secured in a period.